# Which is better to use for bubble chat as performance 9-patch image or RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, layout, nine-patch

I want to just know about which is better to use for bubble chat 9-patch image or custom view create using `RelativeLayout`.

I am looking better solution as performance with example.

What doing `Recyclerview` in backgorund if i am using 9-patch ?

What doing `Recyclerview` in backgorund if i am using `RelativeLayout` ?

If the 9-patch is better then why?

If the `RelativeLayout` is better then why?

Comment: 9 patch is best

Comment: 9 patch is easy and best solution

Comment: Yes, 9-patch image is a good solution to use for your chat bubbles. You can see more details https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: @NJ i am not looking easy solution, i am looking for better as performance and memory optimisation

Comment: That is what my answer's second part says the `and best solution ...`

Answer (score 0):

9-patch image is best solution because

> A NinePatchDrawable graphic is a stretchable bitmap image, which Android will automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the View in which you have placed it as the background. An example use of a NinePatch is the backgrounds used by standard Android buttons — buttons must stretch to accommodate strings of various lengths.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: I already read that document but not mention related to performance, about how much memory it take in background.

Answer (score 0):

For chat bubbles, 9-patch images are the best solution. When you use RecyclerView , don't worry about background process. This OnCreateViewHolder method is handling everything for you:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```